# Is there any REST API to get online users in quickblox in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, chat, quickblox

I am developing a chat application in rails with the help of quickblox. I have created the application in quickblox and setup it in the rails app. With the help of API, I can get the list of registered users. But I need to get a list of online users. How to get it. Is there any API available to get the list of online users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get online/offline statuses of any user

You can use **user.last_request_at** for such purpose, but it's not 100% 'true' status

http://quickblox.com/developers/Users

What else you can do is to implement Chat Roster. It allows to manage a user's contact list. And you can track your contact list user online/offline status as you can see on Skype for example

There are a lots of Ruby XMPP libraries

http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/

How to interact with QuickBlox Chat http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat